# how to implement a stateful ns3 proxy node

Tags: proxy, server, forward, ns-3

I am trying to simulate a network consist of a server, n clients and m proxy servers in `ns3`. my clients can only see proxies and connect them(proxies are my clients sink application). I want my proxies to forward the exact traffic to  server( server is sink for my proxies) and return back the servers response to clients.

How can I achieve this? can anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to create a 'Proxy' application which would receive on one interface/port and forward to another. Your client would connect to the proxies and send their data. The proxy would receive and forward them to the server.
You can use the `UdpEchoServer` application as base of your Proxy application. The UdpEcho receives a packet and replies to the sender with a new one. Modify this by replying to another node (your server) and instead of creating a new packet, use the same (or copy of the received).

Comment: but how can I be sure which response that server is returning is for which client. how can I have state of all packets?

Comment: You could add a header or a packet tag or simply use a different port number. That's how flow multiplexing works.